# Шорткоды Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Вывожу на странице товары с помощью шорткода [product_page].
Товаров около 100.
Мне нужно выводить их по 8 с пагинацией.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Речь о woocommerce?

Comment: Да. В файле single-product.php прописан вывод товара в карточке. Нужно вывести эти карточки в полном виде на кастомную страницу с пагинацией по 8 штук. На кастомную страницу товары выведены через shortcode [product_page = id""]. Но пагинации, естественно, нет. При вводе нужного скрипта с ограничением вывода товаров "8" в вышеуказанный файл ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте запрос по товарам через WP_Query с пагинацией. А при выводе товара используйте шорткод.

```php
<?php

$current_page = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args         = [
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'paged'          => $current_page,
];

$products = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $products->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $products->have_posts() ) {
        $products->the_post();

        // Output the product.
        echo do_shortcode( '[product_page id="' . $post->ID . '"]' );
    }

    // Reset post data after cycle.
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    echo '<p>No products.</p>';
}

// Pagination.
$pagination_args = [
    'base'      => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
    'total'     => $products->max_num_pages,
    'current'   => $current_page,
    'format'    => '?paged=%#%',
    'prev_next' => true,
    'prev_text' => __( '&laquo; Previous' ),
    'next_text' => __( 'Next &raquo;' ),
    'type'      => 'plain',
    'end_size'  => 2,
    'mid_size'  => 2,
];

$paginate_links = paginate_links( $pagination_args );

if ( $paginate_links ) {
    echo '<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">';
    echo $paginate_links;
    echo '</nav>';
}
```

Comment: Добавляю Ваш код в файл шаблона моей кастомной страницы. Пагинация работает и показывает две страницы, что говорит о том, что разбивка на страницы произошла. Но вот содержимое отсутствует. Вывода на страницу самих товаров нет.

Comment: По коду же видно, что я ошибся в формета шорткода. Замените строку с шорткодом на такую `echo do_shortcode( '[product_page id="' . $post->ID . '"]' );`. Ответ я поправил.

Comment: Получая советы от такого гуру, как Вы, поневоле не задумываешься об ошибках. ))) Спасибо. Ваше лекарство помогло.

Comment: Чем джун отличается от синьора? Оба могут скопировать код со StackOverflow, но синьор его разберет по косточкам и поправит :)

Comment: Если ответ принят, его стоит отметить галочкой внизу. Если информация в ответе полезна, можно нажать на стрелку вверх. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что вы используете Wordpress старше версии 3.2. В таком случае попробуйте такой shortcode

```
[products limit="8" columns="4" paginate="true"]
```

В результате должен получиться вывод 8-ми товаров в 2 строки 4 колонки. Если товаров больше, чем 8 (100 в вашем случае), то где-то справа сверху-снизу должна появиться постраничная навигация

Comment: С этим шорткодом я знаком. Он выводит товары списком. Мне же нужно вывести именно product_page. В файлах я пытался добавить скрипт ограничения вывода, но он не работает именно потому, что на моей кастомной странице выведены шорткоды.